# in Jquery why it won't alert each one in while loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, while-loop, alert

```
<body>
    <div id="div1">1</div>
    <div id="div2">2</div>
    <div id="div3">3</div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var boxNumber=1;
        while(boxNumber<=3){
            $('#div'+boxNumber).click(function(){
                alert(boxNumber);
            });
            boxNumber++;
        }
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

I expected the code to alert its box number when i click on it, but it alerted number 4 instead. how do i fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're alerting the current value of the counter, not the actual value of the `<div>`.

This will work how you expect:

```
<body>
    <div id="div1">1</div>
    <div id="div2">2</div>
    <div id="div3">3</div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var boxNumber=1;
        while(boxNumber<=3){
            $('#div'+boxNumber).click(function(){
                alert($(this).text());
            });
            boxNumber++;
        }
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rceCD/)

Comment: Thanks,that works fine. but why the counter(boxNumber) in alert and the counter(boxNumber) in $('#div'+boxNumber) are different? and both of them inside the while loop.

Comment: You're not actually binding that value to the click of the DIV.

Answer (score 1):

You're incremeting boxNumber to 4 as soon as the page is loaded - was this intentional?  See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r8X3H/) for clarification.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var boxNumber = 1;
    while (boxNumber <= 3) {
        $('#div' + boxNumber).click(function () {
            alert($(this).text());
        });
        boxNumber++;
        alert(boxNumber);
    }
    alert(boxNumber);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer of @john you can do this too, which is simpler

```
 var boxNumber=1;
    while(boxNumber<=3){

function addClick(num) {    
    $("#div" + boxNumber).click (
        function() { alert (num) }
    )
}
addClick(boxNumber);
boxNumber++;
}
```